# Modify Object Public Variables in Unity Timeline

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script to control unique properties of a given character.

Im looking for ways to be able to change public variables of this given script inside a timeline, or simply remove/deactivate a gameobject.

Ideally, something more "generic" would be running some piece of code inside the timeline, having some arguments that could be inputed by configuring the timeline. Could i do things like call methods of scripts in timelines ?

Is this something doable ? I do not want to create animations for every timeline transition.

Would appreciate any help !

Comment: https://blog.unity.com/technology/how-to-use-timeline-signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by a comment above, timeline signals is what solves this problem, as a way to inform external code that a specific timeline point has been reached.